# adding new document to CouchDb using ArmChair throws exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: couchdb-2.0, armchair

Iam using couch-db version 2.2.0

and I want to make crud operations on `couchdb` database using .`Net`

so I installed `Armchair.Core`  Nuget Package version 0.11.2

and in order to add d a new document I, followed the code that is mentioned in
not finished wiki yet 
https://bitbucket.org/dboneslabs/arm-chair/wiki/main-api/session-api.md

```
Database mydatabase = new Database("TestDb",newConnection("http://localhost:5984"));
            using (var session = mydatabase.CreateSession())
            {
                var author = new Person("Jone");
                session.Add(author);// NOTE: If no Id has been assigned before the instance is added to the Session, then ArmChair will assign it. After the object is committed to the database, the revision will then be set onto the instance

                session.Commit();  
            }
```

but I still getting the error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

also `mydatabase` variable mentioned in previous  code  has values null for `Connection` and `DataBase` Parameters even though i passed them in the constructor as it doesn't connect to couchdb database at all and never tries to create database TestDb

any help please ,are there any wrong calls in my code

Answer (score 0):

ArmChair connects to an existing database and does not create one.

if you want to create a database, have a look a look at the *sample application*, in the Autofac registration there is a method which ensures that there is a database created.

https://bitbucket.org/dboneslabs/arm-chair/src/bd4e70d6c51d8b45cfb89eb65ecf81a4ecefb691/samples/todo/Todo.Service/Infrastructure/Modules/DataAccessModule.cs#lines-62

its not the pretty-est of code but works.